Converting shapefiles into GeoJSON
Does anyone know where I can convert multiple ArcGIS files (.cpg .dbf .prf .sbn .sbx .shp .shx) into GeoJSON/TopoJSON for free?
MyGeodata Converter works perfectly but I don't want to subscribe for a one-time use.

Open the shapefiles in QGIS, then just right click and Save As GeoJSON.

Install QGIS if you want to have GUI, or GDAL if you prefer command line.

You can try here: https://products.aspose.app/gis/conversion/shapefile-to-geojson

MyGeodata Converter allows you to pay for a single conversion after you exceed the free conversion limit - no subscription required...

try https://quickmaptools.com/, especially if you have larger files!

There were no details provided regarding the number of shapefiles that have to be converted. However, there are several free approaches that I may suggest:

software

QGIS. The whole procedure is described in this article on GitHub


programmatically

using ogr2ogr package from GDAL library
ogr2ogr test.geojson test.shp




on the Web
There are several websites available:

MyGeodata Converter: https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-geojson
ASPOSE: https://products.aspose.app/gis/conversion/shapefile-to-geojson
MapOG Converter Tool: https://mapanalysis.mapog.com/converter
mapshaper: https://mapshaper.org/
Ogre: https://ogre.adc4gis.com/




References:

Converting shapefiles to Geojson
Different ways to convert Shapefile to GeoJSON – Online or Offline or API
Using ogr2ogr to convert Shapefiles to GeoJSON
How to convert shape file to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr?


ESRI Shapefile to GeoJSON
Example only
(not for bulk loading)

Please note this is intended for demo-ing the capabilities for FME Flow (formerly FME Server).
https://demos-safe-software.fmecloud.com/fmeserver/apps/EasyTranslator
